# Q&A mechanism based on SHA256 - fast or reverse computing problem

Tags: c, cryptography, reverse, sha256

There is a question and answer mechanism. It consists in the fact that the question "Q" is 4 bytes, for eg. 0xAA 0xBB 0xCC 0xDD. The answer "A" is generated in such a way that the sequence "S" with a length of 8 bytes is added to the question "Q". A sequence of 12 bytes is then created. The SHA256 hash function of that 12 byte string is then computed. The first 4 bytes of the calculated SHA256 value are the response "A". So, for example:

Q = 0xAA, 0xBB, 0xCC, 0xDD

S = 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08

SHA246 (AABBCCDD0102030405060708) = e455df10f57a47498c12c5eaad9b93f525aba1252a7a3a7fee160878db0b6aa8

so: A = e455df10 (first 4 bytes).

I know 3 pairs of sample Q questions and A answers. The goal is to calculate S which is a sequence of 8 bytes.
I wrote a program that adds 8 bytes S to the Q that I know. Then it calculates SHA256 and checks if the first 4 bytes agree with the answer A I know. It is a brute force attack. The problem is that the loop substitution 8 bytes and the SHA256 calculation for the combination 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF is very time consuming (even computing on GPU takes tens of days if not more). Is it possible to find the sequence S in a different way and within a reasonable time?

Here is an example source code:

```
{
    unsigned char S[8];         // this is unknown value to find
    unsigned char Q[] = {0xAA,0xBB,0xCC,0xDD}; 
    // for example:
    // Q: 0xAA,0xBB,0xCC,0xDD
    // A: 0xe4,0x55,0xdf,0x10
        
    unsigned char input[100]={0};
    unsigned char hash[100]={0};
    unsigned char c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6,c7,c8;
        
    for(c1=0xFF;c1>=0;c1--)
        for(c2=0xFF;c2>=0;c2--)
            for(c3=0xFF;c3>=0;c3--)
                for(c4=0xFF;c4>=0;c4--)
                    for(c5=0xFF;c5>=0;c5--)
                        for(c6=0xFF;c6>=0;c6--)
                            for(c7=0xFF;c7>=0;c7--)
                                for(c8=0xFF;c8>=0;c8--)
                                    S[0]=c1;
                                    S[1]=c2;
                                    S[2]=c3;
                                    S[3]=c4;
                                    S[4]=c5;
                                    S[5]=c6;
                                    S[6]=c7;
                                    S[7]=c8;
                                    memcpy(&input[0],Q,5);  
                                    memcpy(&input[5],&S[0],8);
                                    sha256(input,12,hash);
                                    if((hash[0]==0xe4)&&(hash[1]==0x55)&&(hash[2]==0xdf)&&(hash[3]==0x10))
                                    {
                                        //for this example program should find: S = 0x01 0x02 0x03 0x04 0x05 0x06 0x07 0x08
                                        //...but after many many days.
                                        printf("S = ");
                                        for(int i=0;i<8;i++) 
                                            printf("0x%02X ", S[i]);
                                    }   
    return 0 ;
}
```

If someone could advise me on a faster method to solve this problem, I would be very grateful.

Comment: A few days will be fine :) SAT solver? I have never heard. I need to delve into this topic

Comment: The problem as you have posed it and as I understand it cannot be solved by a student in reasonable time using reasonable computing resources. Are you sure you are supposed to calculate an actual S, as opposed to outlining how a millionaire might do it? Or perhaps you known something additional about S that can drastically reduce the work factor? You basically need to do about 2^63 SHA256 hashes on average to solve such a problem. It's doable as you note but very hard.

Comment: A friend has calculated that by writing a program in CUDA C on the average performance of a graphics card, it is possible to find a solution in about 135 days. Perhaps it would be possible to optimize the shortcut function so that the SHA256 function itself would execute in a smaller number of program steps and thus faster. I'm using the following SHA256 code borrowed from here [link](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/digest/blob/master/src/sha256.c). Perhaps there is some other faster free SHA256 implementation that runs faster, and thus the time would be shortened from 135 days to eg. 90 days

Comment: Published benchmarks for hashcat, which tend to be on high-end (not average) GPUs, run about 2^31 to 2^33 H/sec for uniterated SHA256; at those speeds 2^63 trials will take roughly 128 to 512 _years_. Have your friend check again.

Comment: So I counted this time myself again and in fact my friend made a mistake. I already pointed this out to him. It is impossible to find this even in a few months on a single GPU. If I ran a program that I wrote on my graphics card, it would take around 7600 years to search the full range of data :). Hashcat does this a bit "faster". However, these are still hundreds of years for a single GPU.

Comment: I have recently read that an old coal-fired power plant was reactivated in the USA to power over 15,000 cryptocurrency miners. They've already dug up several hundred million dollar bitcoins. Maybe I will report my problem to them. Maybe he will find a solution in a few months :). Even if the hashcat did it in a "reasonable amount of time", it would not find it anyway because we only know the first 5 bytes of the SHA256 hash and the entire SHA256 hash is needed to guess. So my problem has no practical solution.